# Angular ui-calendar events function called twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar, angular-ui

I am developing a project with AngularJS and using Angular-UI UI-Calendar. In my code I initialize eventSources model for ui-calendar to empty array ([]) and set ui-config "events parameter" to a custom function. That function makes an $http request and then calls the callback function given to the events function.

However, I found out that when I load the page or change the month viewed by left or right buttons, events function called twice. How can I solve that?

Here is my code:

```js
function CalendarCtrl($scope, Data){
 var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

 // Stores all events
    var events = [];

    /* config object */
    $scope.uiConfig = {
        calendar:{
            height: 450,
            editable: true,
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
   buttonText: {
    month: "Ay",
    week: "Hafta",
    day: "Gün",
    list: "Ajanda"
   },
   allDayText: "Tüm gün",
   eventLimitText: "daha fazla",
   firstDay: 1,
   timeFormat: 'H:mm',
   axisFormat: 'H:mm',
   lazyFetching: true,
          
          
            // Here listen for calendar change events
   events: getEvents
     }
    };

 // For angular ui-calendar element
 $scope.eventSources = [];

 // Calendar event handlers
 function getEvents(from, to, callback){
  console.log(from);  // For test purposes
      
        // Request for data from server and when it comes, call callback to update calendar
  Data.calendar.get(moment(from).unix(), moment(to).unix()).then(function(events){
   angular.forEach(events, function(event){
    event.start = moment.unix(event.start);
    if(event.end){
     event.end = moment.unix(event.end);
    }
    else{
     delete event.end;
    }

    var d = event.start;
    if(d.hour() == 0 && d.minute() == 0 && d.second() == 0){
     event.allDay = true;
    }

    if(event.important){
     event.className = "important-event";
    }

    event.editable = true;
   });

   callback(events);
  });
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the solution.

Instead of registering an event handler to $scope.uiConfig.calendar.events, register that same function to $scope.eventSources array. Like that:

```
$scope.eventSources = [getEvents];
```

Whenever view changes and calendar needs data it will look at the $scope.eventSources elements. And if an element is a function it will be called and results will be shown in calendar.

Answer (score 1):

We ran into a similar problem in a project and our solution was also in the eventSource initialization putting an empty object inside the array.

$scope.eventSources = [{}];